# Dialog showing different information from DB when clicking on different buttons

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, modal-dialog

I have 10 different images with some data triggered from the database. I have also this piece of code working perfectly fine:

```
  var dialog = document.querySelector('dialog');

  document.querySelector('#show').onclick = function() {
      dialog.showModal();
  };

  document.querySelector('#close').onclick = function() {
      dialog.close();
  };
```

I have the images like this:

```
//Show the image with some data for it    

<div id="show">
      <img src="images/<?php echo $row1["name"]; ?>.png" alt="<?php echo $row1["name"]; ?>" title="<?php echo $row1["name"]; ?>" width="50" height="50"><br>
     <div>
      <span class="nameBox">
        <?php echo $row1["name"]; ?></span>
        <br>
      <span class="nameData">
        <?php echo $ro["phone"]; ?></span>
     </div>
    </div>

//The dialog which will appear after clicking on the image

    <dialog class="myDialog" id="1">
     <span id="close">x</span>
      <h3 class="headerDialog"><?php echo $row1["name"]; ?></h3>
        <p style="background: black; color: white">phone: <?php echo $row["phone"]; ?><br>
      address: <?php echo $row["address"]; ?></p>
    </dialog>
```

Please, do not pay too much attention to the php code as it is working fine. It is showing everything I need as I want. The problem is that, If I apply the javascript+dialog code for the 10 images, it only works for the first one, and not for the rest (that's why you see ...dialog id ="1", cause I was trying to use different ids to solve the issue). It is showing the dialog perfectly fine for the first one, but when I click on any other, nothing happens.

How can I show the dialog everytime I click on any image and then show in the dialog the correct info based on the image I just clicked?

Comment: In your JavaScript, you have no mention of any IDs. So it will likely just find the first one each time. [Rule of three](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_(computer_programming)) also applies here, I would refactor your code so that you’re not writing it out 10 times. Get your images into an array and foreach through them. `<?php foreach ($images as $image) { echo $image['name]'; }` is more sensible.

Comment: Hi Thomas, thanks for the tips. Will do so. My real problem though is not that one...can you help me out with the javascript, please? Thanks!

Comment: Really sorry to have to say this, but it very much is your problem! :D If you write out the PHP, you almost have to write out the JavaScript 10 times. Then if you need to make 1 change, you have to make it 20 times. This means that you will be up late at night crying into your laptop wishing that you’d just fixed it before you moved on – trust me, it’s a hard lesson to learn. Helping you with your JavaScript goes beyond what Stack Overflow is for, so I’ll give you a clue: `document.getElementById(id)`. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks a lot for your NOT help, really appreciated :). If you would have spent the time you took to write that stupid comment to really help me, maybe somebody would have found this helpful (at least me). Now, nobody finds this helpful at all. So, thank you very much! :D